# OKTA - Why does the endpoint {{URL}}/api/v1/sessions/me return me different expiresAt value when I hit it again and again?

Tags: okta, okta-api

Why does the endpoint return different expiresAt value when I hit this endpoint {{URL}}/api/v1/sessions/me again and again?
Initially,expiresAt showed me something like 12:34:56.When I hit is again in 1 minute time,it gave me 12:34:78.But I didnt perform any action in the UI side while that interval.Why is the expiration time getting refreshed?

Answer (score 2):

Making a call to /sessions/me renews the session expiration. It isn't just interaction with the UI that will extend the session, API calls on behalf of the user will extend it as well.

Comment: Also,is there any API in OKTA where I can check session expiration time of apps tied to OKTA?

Comment: Applications sessions are managed on their own and are separate from the Okta one. Also, Okta has no way to keep track of other session lifetimes or expirations. Maybe re-ask the question and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the difference between `/api/v1/sessions/me/lifecycle/refresh` and `/api/v1/sessions/me` ?